# Bash awk script: document splitter issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I wrote this script to split one large document into several 500 line documents. It works with an exception of the first rendered file, which is one line short(499 lines).
The first line of the master document is transferred to "file01" correctly, & line 1 of "file02" is the next sequential line from line 499 of "file01."
Below is my script. Thank you all.
to use in terminal: Splitter.sh "filetosplit.txt"

```
#!/bin/bash

find $1 -type f | sort -n > $1_TapeList.txt


mkdir 500FileTL_$1
cd  500FileTL_$1
awk '{outfile=sprintf("file%02d.txt",NR/500);print > outfile}' ../$1_TapeList.txt
```

Comment: I'd look at how I could use the `split` command instead of doing it myself via awk.

Comment: As an aside: please double-quote all `$1` references. Also, you may run out of file handles in your `awk` script if you don't close previous output files.

Answer (score 1):

NR starts at 1, not 0. So you could just fix it like this

```
awk '{outfile=sprintf("file%02d.txt",(NR-1)/500) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd approach it this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

dir="500FileTL_$1"
mkdir "$dir"

find "$1" -type f |
sort -n |
awk dir="$dir" \
   '(NR-1) % 500 == 0 { 
       outfile = sprintf("%s/file%02d.txt", dir, (NR - 1)/500) 
    } 
    { print > outfile }'
```

No point in slowing things down with bash, or requiring it, if you don't need it.  No need change directories.  No need to create a temporary file, or wait for it to be written.  If you want `$1_TapeList.txt`, add a print statement at the end of the awk script, and redirect that.

Also, you really want `set -e`.  You do not want the script to proceed if **mkdir** fails.

The above won't run much faster because awk can't begin until sort ends.  But there's less wasted motion, and the awk will be a tad faster because it runs sprintf 0.5% as often.